# phpmyadmin export, quote character within string

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

Using phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.14, exporting a table in SQL format results in doubling single quotes within a string: 
    `'O''Neil'`.

My provider recently upgraded to phpMyAdmin 4.7.3, and exporting the same table results in using an escape sequence to include a single quote: 
    `'O\'Neil'`.

While both methods are documented as valid, the escape sequence breaks a separate (offline) program that reads the exported file.

Does phpMyAdmin provide for changing the export method, or are there alternatives, like different file format or character coding?

(Yes, a text editor can replace all occurrences of `\'` with `''` , but ... )
Thanks!